# Unable to SSH into vmware esxi 6.7 host

Tags: ssh, vmware

I want to ssh into vmware esxi 6.7 version but gets permissino denied error.
I have
1- enabled ssh on esxi 6.7 by starting TSM-SSH into host mode
2- created ssh key on remote vm 
3- i can ping esxi 6.7 server
4- esxi port also working
5- in ssh config remote permission set= yes and public key authentication = yes

but still unable to ssh
i am using correct authentications. help me with this as i am new to vmware and don't know other ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is solved by making changes in configuration file of .ssh and checking if any firewall is active.
2. After this we just need to restart our ssh service.
3. With correct username@ip connect to our server.
   This is working for me.